# Cordova-android install

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I followed Cordova's guide for [installing the CLI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) and [creating an Android project](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) using the CLI.

After importing to eclipse there where some issues.  Most of the issues where resolved when I added CordovaLib directory as a Library (right-click project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Class Folder -> /CordovaLib)

One error remains however,

> CordovaWebView cannot be resolved to a type

Take in mind I have written no code; only used the CLI to generate my project.  So the error above is in this generated file:

WhitelistPlugin.java

And in this method:

```
@Override
public void pluginInitialize() {
    if (allowedNavigations == null) {
        allowedNavigations = new Whitelist();
        allowedIntents = new Whitelist();
        allowedRequests = new Whitelist();
        new CustomConfigXmlParser().parse(webView.getContext());
    }
}
```

All of my other references to Cordova classes work fine, so Im not sure whats going on?

FYI

I know others had issues that required updating Android version as well as cleaning the project but my project is currently at the latest (afaik) 5.1.1 22 and I have cleaned many times.

Comment: Eclipse is being deprecated, use android studio

Comment: sure, ill download and install that but the guide is for eclipse, it really should work

Comment: seems like phonegap docs page is outdated, use cordova docs instead, they point to use android studio http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Boss's comment says above using Android Studio did solve this problem.  Though I dont think its the best answer it did resolve the issue.  Will accept other answers if someone knows why the above happens